# Relative xpath not working

Tags: xpath

This xpath works:

```
//*[@class="ccbnOutline"]
```

This xpath doesn't work:

```
.//*[@class="ccbnOutline"]
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: My guess would be that `.` is not the root of your document, but you'd have to show a [mcve].